# Do I have to report my T-Bills on taxes if they haven't yet been matured?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, treasury

Do I have to report on taxes for 2022 year my 4 week T-bill if I buy them on Dec 6, 2022 (Maturity date Jan 3, 2023)?

Comment: What do you think you would be reporting? It seems like you're just asking "do I have to report income I won't receive until next year, this year?"

Comment: @KevinArlin: actually you do sometimes, though not here. If you buy a taxable bond longer than 1 year issued at a discount of more than .25%/year, it _must_ be reported ratably over the years you hold even though you don't actually receive it until redemption or sale; see 'original issue discount' in pub550. Usually the broker gives you form 1099-OID (Original Issue Discount) along with your other 1099's. T bills of course aren't over 1 year, and T notes and bonds (except TIPS) usually have coupon set to keep the issue discount OR premium small.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 this is an answer, not a comment

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I like your explanation. Could you please post it as an answer? I think it will be helpful for other people as well. Thank you.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That makes sense, since otherwise bonds could just avoid taxation for their whole duration by paying from a discount instead of interest, but I wouldn't have guessed it on my own, thanks!

Comment: @RonJohn +Dzianis: for bills, my 'answer' does not apply, and for longer tenors in the (rare) cases it does apply it's dupe https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/91242/capital-gains-tax-on-us-treasury-bonds/ and https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152491/how-do-i-reflect-discount-on-a-treasury-note